Vermiculite removal from fireplace
I have some vermiculate containing 2% asbestos that I need to remove from a fireplace in our living room (see picture).
I've talked to a couple different removal places, who are going to come out and give me a quote for removing. We have a super tight budget at the moment though, since we have paid for multiple other house projects to be completed by professionals this year.
I'm debating on doing the removal myself though, I'm just hesitant because we have small kids in the house. Some remediation technicians have told me doing the removal myself would be ok so long as I'm gentle and spray the vermiculite down before doing the removal.
Want to get some more opinions before going ahead and doing anything.

UPDATE:
My specific questions are:

Is it safe enough for me to collect the vermiculite if I just wet down the vermiculite, bag it up and take it to hazardous waste disposal, so long as I'm careful not to disturb it too much?

If I do collect the material myself should I go to the lengths of creating a barrier and setting up ventilation?

Is it risky enough doing this work that I should just hire a company to do it for me?



Edited and added specific questions to the post.
